# Alias for array or hash element in Ruby

Tags: ruby, alias, variable-alias

Example for array

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c"]
# TODO create an alias for arr[1] as x
x = "X"
# arr should  be ["a", "X", "c"] here
```

Example for hash

```
hash = { :a => "aaa", :b => "bbb" , :c => "ccc" }
# TODO create an alias for hash[:b] as y
y = "YYY"
# hash should be { :a => "aaa", :b => "YYY" , :c => "ccc" } here
```

And also an alias for a variable?

```
var = 5
# TODO create an alias for var as z
z = 7
# var should be 7 here
```

Motivation: I have a big large deep construct of data, and you can imagine the rest. I want to use it in a read-only manner, but due to performance reasons copy is not permissible.

Metaphor: I want to choose context from a larger data structure and I want to access it with a short and simple name.

**UPDATE**: Problem solved as sepp2k advised. I just want to draw a summarizing picture here about the solution.

```
irb(main):001:0> arr = [ { "a" => 1, "b" => 2}, { "x" => 7, "y" => 8 } ]
=> [{"a"=>1, "b"=>2}, {"x"=>7, "y"=>8}]
irb(main):002:0> i = arr[0]
=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2}
irb(main):004:0> j = arr[1]
=> {"x"=>7, "y"=>8}
irb(main):007:0> j["z"] = 9
=> 9
irb(main):008:0> j
=> {"x"=>7, "y"=>8, "z"=>9}
irb(main):009:0> arr
=> [{"a"=>1, "b"=>2}, {"x"=>7, "y"=>8, "z"=>9}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is not possible. There is no feature in ruby that you could use to make your examples work like you want.

However since you're saying you want to only use it read-only, there is no need for that. You can just do `x = myNestedStructure[foo][bar][baz]`. There will be no copying involved when you do that. Assignment does not copy the assigned object in ruby.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to create a method that is your alias, which would update the data.

```
def y=(value)
  arr[:b]=value
end
```

Then call it.

```
self.y="foo"
```

Edit: updated second code snippet.

Comment: No, you can't. You can call it with `self.y = "foo"`, but not with `y = "foo"`. `y = "foo"` will always assign to the local variable `y`, no matter what setter methods are defined.

Comment: 2nd snippet needs to be `self.y = foo`, or else the local variable y is assigned, even when the method y is in scope.